# How to prove commutation relation between charge and current in current algebra?

Tags: special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry, commutator, lie-algebra

I am reading Gauge Theory of Elementary Particle Physics by Tapei Cheng and Lingfong Li. Proceeding equation 5.54, there is a statement which says

> Then from Lorentz covariance, we can include the other components of the currents.

One would then have

$$
\left[ Q^a \left( t \right) , J_{\mu}^b \left( \vec{x} , t \right) \right] = \mathrm{i} C^{a b c} J_{\mu}^c \left( \vec{x} , t \right).
$$

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how would one be able to derive the equation above from Lorentz covariance and the following

$$
\left[ Q^a \left( t \right) , J_0^b \left( \vec{x} , t \right) \right] = \mathrm{i} C^{a b c} J_0^c \left( \vec{x} , t \right).
$$

Can someone give me a hint on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your current is a Lorentz tensor,
$$
\Lambda^{0}_{\mu} J_{0}(\vec{x},t) = J'_{\mu}(\vec{x}',t').
$$
and the charge $Q(t)$ is a Lorentz scalar:
$$
Q^{'}_a(t') = Q_a (t),
$$
we have that
$$
[Q^{'a} (t') , J_{\mu}^{'b} ( \vec{x}',t')] = i C^{abc} J^{'c}_{\mu}(\vec{x},t)
$$
can be written by a Lorentz transformation as
$$
[Q^{a} (t), \Lambda^{0}_{\mu} J_0^{b} (\vec{x} ,t) ] 
= \Lambda^{0}_{\mu} [Q^{a} (t), J_0^{b} (\vec{x} ,t) ] =
i C^{abc} \Lambda^{0}_{\mu} J_0^{c}(\vec{x},t).
$$
Therefore, it follows that if 
$$
[Q^{a} (t), J_0^{b} (\vec{x} ,t) ] =
i C^{abc} J_0^{c}(\vec{x},t).
$$
is true, then
$
[Q^{'a} (t') , J_{\mu}^b ( \vec{x}',t')] = i C^{abc} J^{'c}_{\mu}(\vec{x},t)
$
must also be true being derived by linear transformation from the previous one.

**Some intuition**. The notion of covariance stablishes that there is no prefered 
direction. In absence of interactions every dimension should appear in equal footing in every equation.

Comment: Is the first equation you wrote correct? I don't think so: you are just multiplying $J_0$ by a fixed element $\Lambda^0_\mu$ ($\mu$ and zero are fixed), while the form of a lorentz transformation is $J'_0=\Lambda_0^\nu J_\nu$, with index $\nu$ contracted, meaning you need to know also the spatial components of the current to lorentz transform it. Your equation would imply that you can transform time-like 4-vectors into space-like (it would break causality), which you can't since lorentz tranformation conserves the Minkowski norm $J_\mu J^\mu$ and $J_0 J^0>0$ while $J_i J^i<0$.